# REACTJS Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I get some values ​​from the back end, but I want to convert them to the front end.
I made a Switch, however, it is giving this error that appears in the title.
I also tried with if, but it gave the same error.

If you have any other way of doing this I also accept tips.

Code:

```
export default function Notification() {
    const { guid } = useParams();

    const [appcodeValue, setAppcodeValue] = useState(null);
    const [notify, setNotify] = useState([]);

    function fetchNotifications() {
        setLoading(true);

        api
            .get(`/v1/admin/announcements/${guid}`)
            .then(({ data: notifications }) => {
                setNotify(notifications);
            })
            .catch(() => {
                setError(`Desculpe, não foi possivel carregar a notificação.`);
            })
            .finally(() => {
                setLoading(false);
            });
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchNotifications();
    }, []);

    if (loading) {
        return (
            <Center>
                <Loading size="40" />
            </Center>
        );
    }

    switch (notify.appcode) {
        case 0:
            return setAppcodeValue('Todos');
            break;
        case 1:
            return setAppcodeValue('Associados');
            break;
        case 2:
            return setAppcodeValue('Não Associados');
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    return (
        <>
            <CardAppcode>
                Appcode
                        {!loading && notify ? <p>{appcodeValue}</p> : []}
            </CardAppcode>
        </>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1 - With that approach, you are calling the `setAppCode()` at the moment the component renders. Since it's a `useState` function, it makes the Component re-render. Then it re-renders and call `setAppCode()` again (infinite loop).

2 - (Just to make clear) Since you are using a http request you will only be able to get the notifications from the back-end if you ask. You are only asking it once (the moment the component renders (using useEffect)). In order to do that notifications update dynamically you should use some pushNotifications system.

3 - Your notify variable is an array. So you can't just access property notify. You need to access one of the objects that is inside your array, in my example i'll access the first one.

To solve it I would just call your switch statement after the API request:

```
api.get(`/v1/admin/announcements/${guid}`)
            .then(({ data: notifications }) => {
                setNotify(notifications);
                switch (notify[0].appcode) {
                    case 0:
                        return setAppcodeValue('Todos');
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        return setAppcodeValue('Associados');
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        return setAppcodeValue('Não Associados');
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            })
```

Espero ter ajudado :)

Comment: You helped me yes haha ​​I didn't do exactly as in your example, I will post my answer here
Obrigadaaa

Answer (score 0):

I created a function that receives a value by parameter, and it uses that value to analyze which of the categories fits

```
export default function Notification() {
    const { guid } = useParams();

    const [appcodeValue, setAppcodeValue] = useState(null);
    const [notify, setNotify] = useState([]);

    function fetchNotifications() {
        setLoading(true);

        api
            .get(`/v1/admin/announcements/${guid}`)
            .then(({ data: notifications }) => {
                setNotify(notifications);
            })
            .catch(() => {
                setError(`Desculpe, não foi possivel carregar a notificação.`);
            })
            .finally(() => {
                setLoading(false);
            });
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchNotifications();
    }, []);

    if (loading) {
        return (
            <Center>
                <Loading size="40" />
            </Center>
        );
    }

    function verifyValue(value) {
        switch (value) {
            case 0:
                return 'Todos'
                break;
            case 1:
                return 'Associados'
                break;
            case 2:
                return 'Não Associados'
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    return (
        <>
            <CardAppcode>
                Appcode
                        {!loading && notify ? <p>{verifyValue(notify.appcode)}</p> : []}
            </CardAppcode>
        </>
    )
}
```